# Need to improve code efficiency using numpy functinoality

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to using NumPy, but I believe it is the tool I need to speed up my code. Here is what I want my code to accomplish:

For every row in a 2D numpy array (T), I want to know the number of elements satisfying each of four conditions that depend on a cutoff value, for every cutoff value in another array (T_cuts), all while using as few loops as possible.

Here is a sketch of how I would go about this task using for loops:

```
for row in T:             
    classification_counts = []
    for cut in T_cuts:       
        results = []
        for element in row:   
            results.append(classify(element, cut))
        ones = results.count(1)
        twos = results.count(2)
        threes = results.count(3)
        fours = results.count(4)
        classification_counts.append([ones, twos, threes, fours])
```

The helper function `classify` just returns either 1,2,3, or 4 depending on the relationship between the element of `T` and the cutoff value of `T_cuts`.

For this problem, `T.shape == (1000000,80)` and `T_cuts.shape == (3000,1)`, so using loops has proved to be much too slow.

EDIT: Including full definition of `classify`. The array `corr_stats` contains information on where each of the elements of `T` came from, and the first column is either "type1" or "type2".

```
def classify(cutoff, element):
    i, j = np.where( T == element )
    if element >= cutoff and corr_stats[j,0] == "type1":
        return 1
    elif element >= cutoff and corr_stats[j,0] == "type2":
        return 2
    elif element < cutoff and corr_stats[j,0] == "type2":
        return 3
    elif element < cutoff and corr_stats[j,0] == "type1":
        return 4
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: This problem can't be unravelled without the definition of `classify()`.  That function probably needs to be modified to operate on arrays rather than a scalar and an array.

Comment: Done. And that is a good point, if anyone has any tips on modifying this function it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have flipped the arguments either in the call to or in the function definition of `classify()`.

Comment: And, also, do you need the individual classififications or is this just a step towards the end goal of counting the number of different classifications?

Comment: I just need the number of each classification for every cutoff value, and then I will end up doing some calculations with those numbers. I do not need to know something like "how many times a certain element was classified as 'one'", or like "which elements were classified as 'two'"

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to discuss only the innermost loop:

```
    results = []
    for element in row:   
        results.append(classify(element, cut))
    ones = results.count(1)
    twos = results.count(2)
    threes = results.count(3)
    fours = results.count(4)
    classification_counts.append([ones, twos, threes, fours])
```

Here we call `classify()` once per cell in the row, and the only important result is how many of each value we get.

To eliminate the inner loop, we need to do something like this:

```
    classification_counts.append(classify(row, cut))
```

So:

```
def classify(row, cutoff):
    greater = row >= cutoff
    one = corr_stats == 1
    two = corr_stats == 2
    return \
        (greater & one).sum(),
        (greater & two).sum(),
        (~greater & two).sum(),
        (~greater & one).sum()
```

The above assumes a transformation of `corr_stats` for improved efficiency.   Specifically, you should replace "type1" and "type2" strings with numerals 1 and 2, and organize corr_stats such that it is aligned with the row values, to avoid having to use `np.where()` to find each element's location in T.  This last part may require some thought (I don't know enough to fully figure it out).